# Querying one to many with relation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models set up like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
end
```

I know I can retrieve the book that a given Page belongs to if I have one model, e.g. page.book.  But if I have an arbitrary set of pages, can I retrieve all of the books that all of my pages belong to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can do :
book = Book.first 
 #get pages
 book.pages 

page = Page.first 
 # get the book 
 page.book

To fetch multiple books from multiple pages: 
 pages = Page.last(5) #taking last 5 pages. 
 book_ids = pages.map(&:book_id)
 books = Book.where(id: book_ids) #lists books of last 5 pages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the association created, you can do:

```
pages.book
```

And

```
book.pages
```

Comment: `pages.book` Is this possible?